# DataStax 2.1 Cassandra Java driver MappingSession overhead?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is there a performance overhead of using the new MappingSession of the DataStax Java driver 2.1 in comparison to using the PreparedStatement? Intuitively, it seems like adding mapping from/to User Defined Types would cost you - but would like to see if anybody has solid data to confirm/deny .

thanks!
Marina